# Open JPA ResultSet mapping

Tags: jpa, sqlresultsetmapping

I have an entity called order which contains 10 columns and also has embedded id(composite key)  columns which contains 5 fields in entity order.

Here is my sql query

```
<named-native-query name="OrderQuery" result-set-mapping="OrderQueryResultSetMapping">
  <query>
    <![CDATA[SELECT t0.colum2, t0.column4, to.embededid.colum3, e mbededid.colum1, FROM order  t0 WHERE t0.orderid = ?1 ]]>
  </query>
</named-native-query>
```

I was trying to build sql resultsetmapping in `orm.xml`

```
<sql-result-set-mapping name="OrderQueryResultSetMapping">
  <entity-result entity-class="order">
    <field-result name="column2" column="column_2" />
    <field-result name="column4" column="column_4" />
  </entity-result>
  <entity-result entity-class="orderembededId">
    <field-result name="column3" column="column_3" />
    <field-result name="column4"1column="column_1" />
  </entity-result>
</sql-result-set-mapping>
```

I don't have issues in query execution, but getting error in `sqlResultSetMapping`. I'm getting following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.4.0-r422266:1674604 fatal general error> 
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: [jcc][t4][10145][10897]
[3.58.81] Invalid parameter 0: Parameter index is out of range. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
```

Can we do this kind of mapping? If so, how do client knows what are the columns are populated for Order entity as part of this query?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you probably figured this out yourself already, but there are some typos in your query:

- `to.embededid.colum3` should probably be `to.embededid.column3` (that's what it is called in your mapping anyway, otherwise you should change it in your mapping).
- Your SELECT ends with a comma before the FROM, this is not valid SQL.
- Your mapping has `name="column4"1column="column_1"`, that 1 should not be there.